# Why linked list are more memory efficient than arrays?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linked-list

As we know that linked list not only store the data but also the address of the nodes, then how they are more memory efficient than arrays?

Comment: This is far too vague. Use logic to decide what the conditions are and act on them appropriately.

Comment: You'll have to use `if/else if` construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

Pseudo code:

```
if (condition1 && condition2)
  do_task1;   // both conditions are true
else if (condition1)
  do_task1;   // only ondition 1 is true
else if (condition2)
  do_task2;   // only condition 2 is true

// if neither condition1 nor condition2 is true do nothing
```

Exercise for the reader: Simplify this even further.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is to use `else if`.

Consider this common function:

```
int SetResetLatch(int input, int set, int reset) {
  if (reset)
    return 1;
  else if (set)
    return 0;
  else
    return input;
}
```

In this case, `reset` has priority.  If both `reset` and `set` are set, `reset` has priority.